# How to access outer block variable in inner block when inner block have same variable declaration?

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i=5;
    {
        int i=7;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I want to access outer `i` (`int i=5`) value in `printf` then how it can done?

Comment: Make a pointer before defining the new `i`. ( http://ideone.com/dobQX )

Comment: Most sanely - don't do it.  Use `gcc -Wshadow` to report such shadowing (and probably others), and pay heed.  If you really need to access the outer variable, use a different name for one of the them (the inner or outer).

Comment: @pmg: Sadly the only 'correct' answer to this perverse question is in  the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant part of the C99 standard, section 6.2.1 (Scopes of identiﬁers):

> *4* [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will be a strict subset of the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

#### Update

To prevent [pmg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882621/how-to-access-outer-block-variable-in-inner-block-when-inner-block-have-same-vari/3884427#3884427) from disappearing: You can access the outer block variable by declaring a pointer to it before the hiding occurs:

```
int i = 5;
{
    int *p = &i;
    int i  = 7;
    printf("%d\n", *p); /* prints "5" */
}
```

Of course giving hiding variables like this is never needed and always bad style.

Answer (score 4):

Store the outer `i` in another variable and then declare inner `i`. like-

```
int i = 5;
{
    int p = i;
    int i  = 7;
    printf("%d\n", p); /* prints "5" */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you can't call one 'I' and one 'J'.

Different names for them would allow you to choose either.

Answer (score 1):

Make a pointer to the old `i` before defining the new one. ( demo at http://ideone.com/dobQX )

But I like Jonathan's comment the best!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.  It is hidden by the `i` in the inner-scope.